# Json model not updating

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have model:

```
$scope.newTask = function() {
        return {
            ProjectID: null,
            ProjectName: null,
            Date: getDate(),
            TaskDescription: null,
            TimeWorked: '1',
            Note: null,
            isSaved: false
        };
    };
```

I updated model:

```
$scope.newTask = function() {
    return {
        ProjectId: null,
        ProjectName: null,
        Date: getDate(),
        Task: null,
        TimeWorked: '1',
        Note: null,
        isSaved: false
    };
};
```

After update, my browser returns me model with old an new fields. How I can solve this? I don't need old fields in object...

Comment: Could you provide the way `newTask` is called?

Comment: just close the browser and open one more time, it's nothing wrong with your code from here

Comment: Check your binding on page, looks still there are old properties.